# How to do not exceed the height of the screen's content?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this site [link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/).

[image]

As you can see, the homepage are 3 photos ... If you resize the window appears scroll the content and I do not want this ... I want to be there regardless of screen height of 100% and will not appear scroll.

The height of main content is determined with jQuery code

```
var windowheight = $(window).outerHeight();
var meniu= $('.navbar-fixed-top').outerHeight();
$('#main-content').css('height', 100+'vh');
$('#main-content').css('height', $('#main-content').outerHeight() - 50);
$('#main-content').css('width',contentwh+20);
```

I tried to add height to 100% `#content` and unsuccessfully `#primary` ... nothing changes and everything appears scrolling.
Briefly I want to limit the height of content.
It can do these things with CSS or JS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try with    overflow:hidden;

```
$('#main-content').css('overflow','hidden');
```

Comment: worked but the images (all 3) must fit in the screen, resize occur now if only two

Answer (score 0):

Images have a width and an height of their own so you have to tell css what to do with this images when they are bigger than the container div.

```
Overflow: hidden;
```

will tell the browser to hide what exceed the size of the container div.

```
Overflow: scroll;
```

will tell the browser to add the scroll bar to see the overflowing part.

What you can do is to specify the size of the picture using the script you already have (taking care of the picture ratio) instead of manipulating the container size.

EDIT:
let's imagine you have three images with width 1250, 250 and 500. So all of them toghether takes 2000px. Each image has a relative width so that 1250/2000*100=62,5% and so on. When you know that you can say that 62,5% of your screen width will be the width of that image. To get it's height you have to check the ratio between width and height. Assume that for example the first image has a 937,5 height (4:3) ratio. This means that the new height will be the calculated width divided by 4 multiplied 3.

To set the image width and heigth you can use this jquery code:

```
$(#img_id).width(1250).height(937);
```

You can get windows size with:

```
vpw = $(window).width();  
vph = $(window).height();
```

and then first image width will be:

```
image1w=vpw * 0,625;
```

If you call this function on window.onload and window.onresize you will get what you are looking for. You can do a resizeImage() function and call it like

```
window.onload = function(event) { resizeImage(); }
window.onresize = function(event) { resizeImage(); }
```

Hope this clarify your doubts about this point

Comment: You mean my images should be responsible? I added .img-responsive class but does not change anything

Comment: what is inside the img-responsive class? The images should be just scaled to the right size: if the container becomes 100px widht and 200px height for example the image must be scaled using percentage of its width and height on the same way. So if the pic is 400px height and you set height= 50% then the pic will take only 200px on the div. Is it clear enough?

Comment: http://i57.tinypic.com/14xz5up.png look at this image.I added width: 100% First image and look good on all resolutions, the problem is surrounded ... how I get them to fit on the screen?

Comment: You have to get the scren size and apply some math with the js code you are using. It depends on how you want to place the images

Comment: Can you give me a brief example code please to understand better?

Comment: @cristi did you try to apply my suggestion? Is it now working as expected?

Comment: sorry, just today I saw you answer. Please can you tell me where you got height of 937px?

Comment: it is the scaled height based on the pic ratio (all the numbers are just an example). Generically you can do original_width/original_height*new_width to get the new height to be set. This way your image will be scaled proportionally